# OPENSHIFT Cron job just stop working

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have an hourly cron job which has been running in Openshift free gear for almost a year and has been no problem.  But the past 2 days, cron job stops running automatically.  I have been googling around and still cannot find what went wrong.  Here are what I have checked/done to date

- the service I use to keep the site alive is still up and running as normal.  So it is not a case of being idle.
- force restart the app.  Cron job still not started automatically as it used to.
- fake changes to cron script file and push to Openshift.  Still not fixed this.
- log files looks ok

  Mon May  4 13:01:07 EDT 2015: START hourly cron run

  Mon May  4 13:01:29 EDT 2015: END hourly cron run - status=0

Any advice or pointer as to why it just stop working when there is no change to the app.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed now.  Please open a request at help.openshift.com if you continue to have issues with it.

Comment: It has been fixed (as Corey said) and you can monitor reported issues at https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status as well as on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

The cron job still has not started automatically.  I ended up removing Cron cartridge and add the cartridge back again. Then it is now working as normal.

```
rhc cartridge remove cron -a <app>
rhc cartridge add cron -a <app>
```

Thanks.