# Openshift hourly cron job suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux, cron, openshift, redhat

Suddenly the hourly cron job on openshift stopped working.
I am using a free account and the cron was running fine until suddenly it just stopped working.

Minutely jobs on the other hand are running fine, given the following files

*app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/cminut*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ping'
```

and

*app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/hourly/chour*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'pong'
```

as well as the following permissions

`[xxx-xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com cron]\> ls -la hourly/
total 4
drwx------. 2 1234567 1234567 18 Jun 28 19:04 .
drwx------. 4 1234567 1234567 52 Jun 28 19:04 ..
-rwx--x--x. 1 1234567 1234567 24 Jun 28 19:04 chour
[xxx-xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com cron]\> ls -la minutely/
total 4
drwx------. 2 1234567 1234567 19 Jun 28 19:04 .
drwx------. 4 1234567 1234567 52 Jun 28 19:04 ..
-rwx------. 1 1234567 1234567 24 Jun 28 19:04 cminut
[xxx-xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com cron]\>`

The minutely cron job **runs fine** and i can see the log file *cron_minutely.log* in *$OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR*

For the hourly cron job i **can not** see the *cron_hourly.log* neither the job is executed

My previous attempts wen't trough uninstalling and re installing the cron cartridge as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075234/openshift-cron-job-just-stop-working) but there was no success running the hourly cron job.

Is there any other way that i can debug this, or any openshift specific fix known in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After some desperate attempts and inspecting the cron job cartridge script *cron_runjobs.sh*

i came to note that whenever i runed the hourly cron via this script the log

**":SKIPPED: $freq cron run for openshift user '$OPENSHIFT_GEAR_UUID"**

popped up, such message was not fired for other crons (minutely, weekly...)

upon closer inspection i noticed that there were several processes with this script *cron_runjobs.sh* running on the server, after killing this processes and re-deploying the application the hourly cron job started again to work as expected.

I do not know why were these processes hanged and still running, maybe because i used **sleep** in the hourly cron before, although not sure if that was the reason.